# A recursive function to discuss in Ocaml

Tags: list, function, recursion, ocaml

I have defined a type and a function:

```
type element = ...

let merge (x0: element) (x1: element): element * bool = ...
```

The second part of the return of `merge` represents if `x0` and `x1` are merge-able. If so, the first part of the return is the result of merging, otherwise the first part could be ignored.

Then I would like to realize a function `restructure: element list -> element list` which keeps merging as long as any 2 elements of the list are merge-able (we replace the 2 elements by the result of their merging of couse) the order of merging is not important.

I guess it must be a recursive function, and a little bit complicated for me at this stage, could anyone help?

Thank you very much

Comment: You should use the built-in `'a option` type for the `merge` function.  Then return either `None` or `Some element` for the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I could post a solution but that's neither fun nor very instructive for you :). Instead let me try to give a few hints and if you're still stucked I'll try to help more.

- Indeed, as Nathan suggested, it sounds like your `merge` function should return `option(element)`, which is a classical way to return optional results of functions.
- To write `restructure` I suggest you start with a function `merge_into(res : element, elts : element list)` which will try to merge `elts` into `res`. That should, hopefully, be easier than `restructure`.
- How do you implement `restructure` using `merge_into`?

Don't hesitate to let me know if you still have problems... happy coding! :)